# Is there a way to find elements in nested arrays with mongodb and the $and operator?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

i have a document:

```
"_id": ObjectId("THE DOCUMENT ID"),
   "GROUP NAME": "First Floor",
   "years": {
     "0": {
       "_id": "YEAR ID",
       "year_classes": {
         "0": {
           "class_name": "CLASS A",
           "_id": "CLASS ID",
           "participants": {
             "0": "PARTICIPANT ID" 
          } 
        },
         "1": {
           "class_name": "CLASS B",
           "_id": "CLASS ID",
           "participants": {
             "0": "PARTICIPANT ID" 
          } 
        },
      },
       "year_name": "YEAR 1" 
    },
     "1": {
       "_id": "YEAR ID",
       "year_classes": {
         "0": {
           "_id": "CLASS ID",
           "class_name": "CLASS C",
           "participants": [

          ] 
        } 
      },
       "year_name": "YEAR 2" 
    },
  }
```

It is needed to add another class to a year. The code has the year id through the $YEAR_ID variable (is a string) which the class will be added to.

So, it has to check if the class name, given by $NEW_CLASS_NAME (string variable) has already been used in that year.

I saw the $and operator for mongo but i couldn't manage to get it to work. If it were to be an SQL it would look likt: WHERE `year_id`='$YEAR_ID' AND `class_name`='$NEW_CLASS_NAME'

How could this be done in MongoDB?

---

UPDATE:

The Query of:

{
  "years.year_classes.class_name": $NEW_CLASS_NAME,
  "years._id": $YEAR_ID
}

Is searching the document (so it will always return TRUE) not the same array.

Is there a way to direct the query to find those two values in the same array, so a class with that name, which is in the array of classes which is in the year array with that certain ID?

Comment: in mongoDB, syntax should be something like db.mongoDB.find({year_id:$YEAR_ID, class_name : $NEW_CLASS_NAME}) but i never used mongoDB with PHP ...

Comment: i tried: db.collection.find({ years.year_classes.class_name: $NEW_CLASS_NAME, years._id: $YEAR_ID }) but doesn't return true even if it really is true. I've also tried years:{ year_classes: { class_name: $NEW_CLASS_NAME } }, years:{ _id: $YEAR_ID }, which also didn't work.

Comment: As in SQL, print your request in PHP and try it directly in mongoDB to see what's wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're comparing two conditions inside an embedded object you need to use $elemMatch.
See the general explanation [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29#DotNotation%28ReachingintoObjects%29-Matchingwith%24elemMatch).

Your query structure would be something like:

`db.coll.find({"years":{$elemMatch:{"year_classes.class_name":$NEW_CLASS_NAME,"_id":$YEAR_ID }}})`

Comment: i found out about it yesterday but couldn't manage to use it, your Query example worked perfectly. Thanks!